# android lollipopupdate 5.0.1

Tags: recovery-mode, installation, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update

I am getting the latest OTA update(5.0.1) on my nexus 5, but when the phone restarts and goes to the recovery for the installation of the downloaded file, just 25% into the installation it gives me a error. I do not know what is going wrong. please help

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it just shows 'error' under android symbol with a red triangle.

Comment: I have the same error on my Nexus 4. Is your phone rooted? (mine is)

Comment: If it's rooted, then there is a chance it's due to custom recovery. But as of know, it's still not clear yet.